# Input com fgets

Tags: c, array, string, input, csv

Olá, estou tendo a seguinte dificuldade, no momento em que chamo a função do `fgets`, independente se em algum condicional, ou na função de cadastro ela não funciona. No momento em que compilo não apresenta nenhum erro, simplesmente ele não pede o input do usuário. Não sei se é algo com o código, se puderem me ajudar!

E também como poderia armazenar essas informações em um arquivo CSV ao invés de matrizes.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAX_LIMIT 50

void cadastro(char str[MAX_LIMIT][50], char id){
    printf("Cadastro de um novo funcionário: \nNome: ");
    fgets(str[id], MAX_LIMIT, stdin);
}

int menu(int select){

    printf("\n Menu do programa: \n");
    printf("[1] Cadastrar novo Funcionário \n");
    printf("[2] Listar Funcionários cadastrados \n");
    printf("[3] Exibir relatório de registro de ponto de um funcionário \n");
    printf("[4] Exibir relatório de pendencias de registro \n");
    printf("[5] Gravar registro do ponto \n");
    printf("[0] Sair do programa \n");
    printf("Qual a opção você deseja: ");
    scanf("%d", &select);
    printf("\n");

    return select;
}

int main(){

    int select = 1;
    char id = 0;
    char str[MAX_LIMIT][50]; 

    while (select != 0){
        select = menu(select);
        if (select == 0){
            printf("Você escolheu sair do programa! \n");
        }
        else if (select == 1){
            cadastro(str, id);
        }
        else if (select == 2){
            printf("Lista de funcionários: ");
        }
        else if (select == 3){
            printf("Opção 3 selecionada \n");
        }
        else if (select == 4){
            printf("Opção 4 selecionada \n");
        }
        else if (select == 5){
            printf("Opção 5 selecionada \n");
        }
        else {
            printf(" Digite um comando válido \n ");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Apesar de neste caso específico não fazer diferença (já que MAX_LIMIT = 50) deveria ser: `fgets(str[id], 50, stdin);`. O problema de seu programa é que após a leitura da variável `select` o buffer de entrada está com o caractere '\n'. Uma possível solução é usar: `scanf("%d\n", &select);`.

Comment: Usei como base a sua questão sobre o \n, ok, resolvi parcialmente o problema com um setbuf(stdin, NULL), funcionou. Porém precisava incluir outros inputs após, e esses mesmo colocando o setbuf antes, acaba pulando os fgets.

Comment: De acordo com https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setvbuf.html# a definição de `setbuf` é *assign buffering to a stream*. Não é mais fácil apenas consumir o '\n' ou, como disse pmg não misturar scanf com fgets?

Answer (score 2):

O teu problema é que quando o programa vai executar o `fgets()` o caracter presente no *buffer* de input é um <kbd>ENTER</kbd>. Neste caso, aparentemente, o `fgets()` não funciona pois lê uma linha vazia, apenas com o <kbd>ENTER</kbd>.

Para resolver a situação existem algumas opções:

Limpar o *buffer* de input, **quando necessário**, antes do `fgets()`

```
{ /* limpa stdin */
    int ch;
    do {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == '\n') break;
        if (ch == EOF) break; // erro?
    while (1);
}
fgets();
```

Limpar o *buffer* de input depois do `scanf()`

```
if (scanf("%d", &obj) != 1) /* erro */;
{ /* limpa stdin */
    int ch;
    do {
        ch = getchar();
        if (ch == '\n') break;
        if (ch == EOF) break; // erro?
    while (1);
}
```

ou, **usar sempre `fgets()` para input, e manter sempre o *buffer* de input limpinho**

```
//if (scanf("%d", &obj) != 1) /* erro */;
fgets(data, sizeof data, stdin);
if (sscanf(data, "%d", &obj) != 1) /* erro */;
```